# bash: FQDN to an LDAP DN string

Tags: bash, parsing, ldap, fqdn

I am configuring an LDAP server from a bash script and I need to convert the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) to ldap DNs.

**For example:**

- com -> dc=com
- world.com -> dc=world,dc=com
- hello.world.com -> dc=hello,dc=world,dc=com
- hello.beautiful.world.com -> dc=hello,dc=beautiful,dc=world,dc=com

My bash function works, but it is a little bit verbose. Is there any built-in one-line bash command that I can use? Or how to make my function less verbose?

**My code:**

```
#!/bin/bash 
 
function fqdn_to_ldap_dn() {  
   local fqdn parts dn                         
   fqdn="$1"              
   IFS=. parts=(${fqdn##*-})     
   dn=""                            
                              
   for i in "${parts[@]}" ; do
      dn+="dc=$i,"            
   done                          
   dn=${dn%?};                   
   echo $dn                          
}                             
                              
echo $(fqdn_to_ldap_dn "aa.hello.com")
```

Comment: `bash` doesn't have any shortcuts for stuff like this. It's not the best language for string processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
fqdn_to_ldap_dn() {
  sed -e 's/[^ ]*/dc=&/g' <<<"${1//./ }" -e 's/ /,/g'
}
```

Wrapping that in the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

fqdn_to_ldap_dn() {
  sed -e 's/[^ ]*/dc=&/g' <<<"${1//./ }" -e 's/ /,/g'
}

domains="
com
world.com
hello.world.com
hello.beautiful.world.com
"

for domain in $domains; do
    echo "$domain -> $(fqdn_to_ldap_dn $domain)"
done
```

We get:

```
com -> dc=com
world.com -> dc=world,dc=com
hello.world.com -> dc=hello,dc=world,dc=com
hello.beautiful.world.com -> dc=hello,dc=beautiful,dc=world,dc=com
```

---

Breaking down that command a bit, we have:

- `${1//./ /}` replace all instances of `.` in `$1` with   (a space). See the "Parameter Expansion" section of the Bash man page for details.
- The `sed` expression `s/[^ ]*/dc=&/g` searches for all groups of non-space characters and adds `dc=` in front of them (the `&` in the replacement means "whatever we matched in the first part of the expression").
- The `sed` expression `s/ /,/g` replaces all spaces with `,`

Answer (score 2):

```
f=hello.beautiful.world.co
dn=dc=${f//./,dc=}
echo $dn  # => dc=hello,dc=beautiful,dc=world,dc=com
```

The crucial point here is the double-slash in the parameter expansion, which means *substitute **all** occurances* of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Using the builtin `read`, and [IFS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS); something like:

```
function fqdn_to_ldap_dn() {
  local fqdn parts prefix
  fqdn="$1"
  prefix='dc='
  IFS=. read -ra parts <<< "$fqdn" &&
  (IFS=,; printf '%s\n' "${parts[*]/#/"$prefix"}")
}

fqdn_to_ldap_dn "hello.beautiful.world.com"
```

---

Or bash 5.2 has the loadable builtins like the `dsv`, something like:

```
function fqdn_to_ldap_dn() {
  local fqdn parts prefix
  enable dsv || return
  fqdn="$1"
  prefix='dc='
  dsv -a parts -d "." -S -- "$fqdn" &&
  (IFS=,; printf '%s\n' "${parts[*]/#/"$prefix"}")
}

fqdn_to_ldap_dn "hello.beautiful.world.com"
```

---

A test run on the domains:

```
domains=(com world.com hello.world.com hello.beautiful.world.com)

for f in "${domains[@]}"; do
  printf %s "$f -> "
  fqdn_to_ldap_dn "$f"
done
```

---

Output:

```
com -> dc=com
world.com -> dc=world,dc=com
hello.world.com -> dc=hello,dc=world,dc=com
hello.beautiful.world.com -> dc=hello,dc=beautiful,dc=world,dc=com
```

---

- The `/#/` is a form of non-standard (bash) [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)
  Some [examples](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)
- See [Command Grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) from the manual.
- Also note that the `function` keyword is not needed with your given syntax.

Comment: With Bash 5.2.15 (on both Fedora 38 and Ubuntu 23.04/Lunar Lobster), `enable dsv` returns `enable: dsv: not a shell bulitin`. Maybe that's something that has to be enabled at compile time?

Comment: loadable builtins, most probably a separate package from the distro.